# How to update text input values while using v-for

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I've looked at quite a few questions here but none of them work for my situation from the best I can figure.

Here's the setup:

1. on my page I have a computed object named `ownerQuestions`
2. I use `v-for` to loop through this object and populate a component with it's values
3. this component generates inputs on the page
4. initially these inputs are disabled
5. the user clicks an `Edit` button and the inputs are changed to being editable to allow the user to edit the values.
6. when the user clicks the `Edit` button I use `v-if` to change it to a `Cancel` button
7. if the user clicks `Edit`, makes changes to any of the inputs and then clicks `Cancel` the values of the inputs should go back to their original values from before the user made any changes.

Here's the code from the page. I have tried to strip out some things to make it simpler, hopefully I haven't taken anything out that is important for illustration purposes:

```
<template>
  <section class="d-flex flex-column container">
    <div class="text-center align-self-center app-page" v-if="loadingQuestions || !ownerQuestions.length">
      <h3>Getting Questions</h3>
      <div class="spinner mx-auto mb-3"></div>
    </div>
    <section class="align-self-center app-page" v-else>

      <!-- owner info display -->
      <div class="question-group-header">
        <h4 class="text-truncate">Owner Information</h4>
        <a href="javascript:;" v-if="displayOnly" @click="editTextInputs()" class="edit-button ml-2"><no-ssr><i class="far fa-pencil"></i></no-ssr><span id="ownerInfoEditBtn" class="d-sm-inline d-none editBtn1">Edit</span></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" v-else @click="cancelEditTextInputs()" class="edit-button ml-2"><no-ssr><i class="far fa-pencil"></i></no-ssr><span id="ownerInfoEditBtn" class="d-sm-inline d-none editBtn1">Cancel</span></a>        
      </div>

      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between mb-5">
        <div id="questions" v-for="(question, index) in ownerQuestions" :key="question.id" class="col-12 col-md-6 px-0 py-2
              d-flex flex-wrap align-content-start
              border-bottom border-gray-200 question-wrap">
          <borrower-attribute              
              :question="question"
              v-model="question.value"
              :update-index="index"
              :invalidity="invalidity"
              formLayout="inline"
              @answer="updateQuestion" 
              v-bind:id="question.id"
              :displayOnly="displayOnly"></borrower-attribute>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import BorrowerAttribute from '~/components/borrowerAttributes/BorrowerAttribute.vue'
import Modal from '~/components/modal.vue'
import { mapGetters, mapState } from 'vuex'
import QuestionsStore from '~/store/questions.store'
import documentsModule from '~/store/documents'
import { displayValue } from '~/libs/borrower-attribute'
import { authDownload } from '~/libs/upload-service'
import EditQuestionsModal from '~/components/EditQuestionsModal.vue'
import SmoothScroll from '~/libs/smooth-scroll'
import { lsUtils } from '~/libs/ls-utils-service'
import orderBy from 'lodash/orderBy'

export default {
  name: 'Submit',
  layout: 'renewal-app',
  components: {
    'borrower-attribute': BorrowerAttribute,
    'modal': Modal,
    'edit-questions-modal': EditQuestionsModal
  },
  data () {
    return {
      submitting: false,
      invalidity: {},
      displayOnly: true,
      baseOwnerQuestions: {},
      backupOwnerQuestions: {}
    }    
  },
  async beforeCreate () {
    await this.$store.dispatch('borrower/getBorrower', {'forceReload': true})
    await this.$store.dispatch('borrower/getBorrowerValues')
  },
  mounted () {
    SmoothScroll.goTo(0)
    const currentProgress = this.$store.state.progress.appProgress['submit']
    if (!currentProgress || currentProgress < 1) {
      this.$store.dispatch('progress/saveProgressTab', { key: 'submit', value: '1' })
    }        
  },
  async created () {
    await this.$store.dispatch('borrower/getBorrower')
    if (!this.ownerQuestions.length) {
      await this.$store.dispatch('questions/initializeSubmitPage')
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      authUser: state => state.authUser,
      borrower: state => state.borrower,
      loadingQuestions: state => state.questions.loadingQuestions
    }),
    ...mapGetters('questions', [
      'reviewQuestions',
      'displayableQuestions'
    ]),
    ...mapGetters('document', ['requirements']),
    ownerQuestions () {
      return orderBy(
        this.reviewQuestions.filter((q) => q.appSection === 'personalInfo'),
        ['group', 'groupOrder'], ['desc', 'asc']
      )
    }
  },
  methods: {    
    updateQuestion ({ attr, isInvalid }) {
      if (!attr || attr.alias === undefined) {
        return false
      }
      if (isInvalid) {
        return false
      }
      this.$store.commit('questions/mergeAnswers', { [attr.alias]: attr })
    },
    async submitApp () {
      await this.$store.dispatch('borrower/getBorrower')
      await this.$store.dispatch('borrower/setApplicationComplete')
      this.$router.push('/dashboard')
    },
    download (path, params, newTab, filename) {
      return authDownload(path, params, newTab, filename)
    },
    editTextInputs () {
      var editFields = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
      this.backupOwnerQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.ownerQuestions));
      for (var i = 0; i < editFields.length; i++) {        
          this.displayOnly=false
          editFields[i].style.border = "1px solid black";
      }      
    },
    cancelEditTextInputs () {
      this.ownerQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.backupOwnerQuestions));
      var cancelEditFields = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
      this.displayOnly=true
      for (var i = 0; i < cancelEditFields.length; i++) {
        cancelEditFields[i].style.border = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In my attempt I create an object named `backupOwnerQuestions`, then in the `editTextInputs` javascript function I set this object equal to the original values from my `ownerQuestions` object. And lastly, in my `cancelEditTextInputs` function I try to set the `ownerQuestions` back to the values stored in the `backupOwnerQuestions` object.

But, this doesn't work, hence my asking this question. I don't even know if this is the right approach to take. Please let me know if additional information is needed from me.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to try to make your sample code simpler. There is still a lot of code however. Things like classes and extra markup (header tags, wrapping divs etc) can be removed if your code does not depend on them. Its also a good idea to strip out any code not relating to your problem (in this case things like your loading and submitting logic). Also, if you haven't already, read [mcve]. Hope these pointers will help you asking in future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
this.ownerQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.backupOwnerQuestions));
```

`ownerQuestions` is a computed property, defined by the function:

```
ownerQuestions () {
  return orderBy(
    this.reviewQuestions.filter((q) => q.appSection === 'personalInfo'),
    ['group', 'groupOrder'], ['desc', 'asc']
  )
}
```

So you can't just overwrite it. Even worse, you're editing fields on the `reviewQuestions` object by passing them, via `ownerQuestions` to a `v-model` directive. Since `reviewQuestions` comes from a vuex store, it should only be edited using mutations.

You could try creating a copy to edit, and then reverting back to the original when editing is canceled, rather than editing the original and having it change for anything that has a pointer to it.

Something like:

```
this.editableQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.ownerQuestions));
```

Then `v-for` over `editableQuestions` and when the user cancels an edit, simply call

```
this.editableQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.ownerQuestions));
```

again. This approach may need some more work on your part to assimilate it fully into your code. I'm mainly just trying to identify the problem and point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this concept is what I was going for, now I just need to  know where to assign `this.editableQuestions` in my page to get the values initially. Should it be in `mounted` or someplace else?

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak Yeah so long as the data is available in the mounted hook (ie so long as the `reviewQuesrions` vuex property isn't being set after the mounted hook) that would be the ideal place.